# Websocket on Android 4.4 with Phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, websocket

I'm working on an app which needs Websocket to communicate with my server. I'm working with Phonegap so I can run all the code first of all in my browser. 
Since Android 4.4 Websockets got native support in Android so it should work...
I've implemented the Websocket with this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log('websocketready');
    startwebsocket();
});
var ws;

function startwebsocket() {
    ws = new WebSocket('ws://192.168.1.131:8080/.....');

    ws.onopen = function () {
        console.log("Websocket Ready!!");
    }
    ws.onclose = function () {
        console.log("Websocket Closed!!");
    }
    ws.onerror = function () {
        console.log("Websocket Error!!");
    }
    ws.onmessage = function (data) {
        console.log('getvalue : ' + data.data);
    }
}

function sendMessage(temp) {
    ws.send(temp);
}
```

This is just working fine in my browser (Chrome and firefox). But if I start the app with Phonegap on my Nexus 5 with android 4.4.2 I'm getting : 'WebSocket connection to 'ws://192.168.1.131:8080/.....' failed: Unexpected response code: 403'

Do you have any suggestions what I could have missed to do or what I did wrong?

Comment: try adding res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "*"); in your function in server.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, but I don't understand which object 'res' should be?

Comment: Sorry i thought you were using node.js as your server. you need to add access-control-allow-origin in your server to allow your mobile device to communicate with socket.

Comment: Mhm that should not be the problem, because it's just working fine with chrome on my smartphone. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @Thunder have you found a solution?

Comment: Well on some older devices it might be a problem, maybe the native plugin (https://github.com/mkuklis/phonegap-websocket) helps you there. But on a Nexus 5 this should not be a problem. But actually I think it is more a problem of the connection to the server! Can you really access the 192.168.1.131 from your mobile phone as well? Make sure, that it is in the same network and that the incoming requests are accepted for that port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you provide 192.168.1.131 as authorised origin to cordova ?

Maybe you should try to add that to your config.xml :

```
<access origin="192.168.1.131" />
```

Take a look [here](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html) for more informations.

Hope that help :)